# sub posts to parent post

Tags: posts

How to make a sub posts like this example 
http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SGH-I717RWAATT
Overview  Features  Specs  Gallery ....

with link structure just like it! 
....cell-phones/SGH-I717RWAATT-features
....cell-phones/SGH-I717RWAATT-specs

can't find any plugin or something to do this!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress posts are non-hierarchical and therefore cannot have child posts

Most likely the model in question has a hierarchical category(taxonamy) associated with it.

EG:
Country > Technology type > product type > model

Using the catagories like this will give you the required url structure once you assign a pretty permalink structure http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you mean pages, not posts? This is easy to do with pages--you just specify the parent page when editing a page. The url format would be different though--the sub-page would be set off by a slash, not hyphen (barring some hacking).

Comment: No, i want posts not pages !
could it be done through custom fields >> build a sub post or attached page for specific custom field?

Comment: Hmmm. There are probably a few ways to approach this. If you know that you'll always be using exactly the same kinds of sub-posts (eg "specs/features/gallery"), you could fake it by creating a custom post type that has all of those fields merged into it, and only showing the correct sub-part in response to a specific URL structure. I'm a little out of my depth on that.